# extract sentences by using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a markdown file like below:

```
#2016-12-24
| 单词 | 解释 | 例句 |
| --------- | -------- | --------- |
|**accelerator;**| - | - |
|**compass**| - | - |
|**wheels**| - | - |
|**fabulous**| - | - |
|**sweeping**| - | - |
|**prospect**| - | - |
|**pumpkin**| - | - |
|**trolley**| - | - |
|snapped,**| - | - |
|tip| - | - |
|lap| - | - |
|tether.| - | - |
|damp| - | - |
|triumphant| - | - |
|sarcastic| - | - |
|missed out| - | - |
|sidekick| - | - |
|considerable| - | - |
|Willow.| - | - |
|eagle.| - | - |
|considerably.| - | - |
|flat.| - | - |
|feast| - | - |
|scramble| - | - |
|turned up| - | - |
|rounded off| - | - |
|rat| - | - |
|resembled| - | - |
|By the time she had clambered back into the car,| - | - |
|By the time she had clambered back into the car, they were running very late,| - | - |
|wheeled his trolley| - | - |
|barrier,| - | - |
|bounced| - | - |
|in blazes| - | - |
|clutching| - | - |
|sealed| - | - |
|stunned.| - | - |
|‘We’re stuck,| - | - |
|marched off| - | - |
|accelerator| - | - |
|and the prospect of seeing Fred and George’s jealous faces| - | - |
|protest.| - | - |
|in protest.| - | - |
|horizon,| - | - |
|knuckles| - | - |
|metal| - | - |
|thick| - | - |
|reached the end of its tether.| - | - |
|Artefacts| - | - |
|blurted out.| - | - |
|gaped| - | - |
|I will be writing to both your families tonight.| - | - |
|‘Can you believe our luck, though?’| - | - |
|‘Skip the lecture,’| - | - |
|people’ll be talking about that one for years!’| - | - |
|nudged| - | - |
|‘I know I shouldn’t’ve enjoyed that or anything, but –’| - | - |
|dashed| - | - |
```

I'd like to extract the sentences like:

1. By the time she had clambered back into the car,
2. By the time she had clambered back into the car, they were running very late,
3. wheeled his trolley
4. ‘We’re stuck,
5. and the prospect of seeing Fred and George’s jealous faces
6. reached the end of its tether.
7. I will be writing to both your families tonight.
8. ‘Can you believe our luck, though?’
9. ‘Skip the lecture,’
10. people’ll be talking about that one for years!’
11. ‘I know I shouldn’t’ve enjoyed that or anything, but –’

I tried to do like this in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HtGPyl/1) website, but actually each time it match all.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: What is the criterion that determines what to extract? A minimal number of words?

Comment: Maybe you need https://regex101.com/r/ltZXHV/1? Please recheck the requirements.

Comment: @languitar  No particular criterion, actually there are the single word and the sentences in the markdown format table, what I want is to extract the sentences only, and ignore the single word.

Comment: But why would `in blazes` not be matched? It is more than one word.

Comment: @MarcoMei update your question by using your comment

Comment: @ languitar Sorry  languitar, I just missed it out, forgot to paste it... Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could come up with:

```
^\|                     # start of line, followed by |
(                       # capture the "words"
    (?:[‘\w]+           # a non-capturing group and at least one of \w or ‘
        (?:[^|\w\n\r]+  # followed by NOT one of these
        |               # or
        (?=\|)          # make sure, there's a | straight ahead
    )
){2,})                  # repeat the construct at least 2 times
\|
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZldAmA/1) (and mind the modifiers!).
This will capture at least **two consecutive** words, if you need more, put another number in the `{}` parentheses.

Comment: I've been thinking of so long time how to match the consecutive words, thanks very much. finally I update it to: (?<=\|)
(
    (?:[‘\w]+
        (?:[^|\w\n\r]+
        |
        (?=\|)
    )
){2,})
(?=\|)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\|[^\w\|]*(\w+\s+(?=\w+)[^\|]*)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/HtGPyl/3)

1. `^\|` matches if the the line starts with a pipe (|)
2. `[^\w\|]*` grab anything which not in a-z0-9 and |
3. `\w+\s+` makes sure it is followed by a word and one or more
   white space
4. `(?=\w+)` Then checks if it has more words to follow
5. `[^\|]*` if previous conditions found then grabs anything until the
   next pipe |

For each match, group 1 contains the sentence you desire

[Run the Code Sample here](http://ideone.com/0h6BTf)

Comment: Thanks very much, Maverick, it works well.  one more question: according to your answer, can I update it to: `(?<=\|)|[^\w\|]*(\w+\s+(?=\w+)[^\|]*)`. then it will match the sentence only, am I correct?

Comment: You get the sentence in group 1, in the explanation link provided ... try to to avoid lookbehind as much as possible... can show you, how you get the sentence from group 1 ... let me know

Comment: @Marco Mei, I have added the link to run the sample, and you can only accept one answer I guess :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a good coding site, save it.   Hope I can feedback you more if I can. :)